# Center search bar in navigation controller swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I need to change the orientation of a search bar in a navigation controller to be set to the center. I have created the search bar programmatically with this code:

```
lazy   var searchBar:UISearchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRectMake(100, 40, 440, 40))
```

and in viewDidLoad:

```
searchBar.placeholder = "Search for Places"
        var leftNavBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView:searchBar)
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftNavBarButton
```

However I also have a barButtonItem in the left. This has been set through the interface.

[image]

The issue is that when I add the search bar through the code, the screen does not display the button as it gets covered as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

How can I shift the search bar to show the menu button followed by the search bar in the center?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the reason are you assigned the `searchBar` to `leftBarButtonItem` that the reason it shows in left side , if you need in center of Navigation add your search to `titleView` for navigation bar, change this

```
     searchBar.placeholder = "Search for Places"
    var leftNavBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView:searchBar)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftNavBarButton
```

to

```
 lazy   var searchBar:UISearchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 440, 40))
searchBar.placeholder = "Search for Places"
self.navigationItem.titleView = searchBar // or use self.navigationcontroller.topItem?.titleView = searchBar
```

Comment: for ex see this link http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/customizing-navigation-bar-ios8-swift

Answer (score 2):

Your search bar is on the left because you're setting left navigation button. Try to change `titleView` instead.

```
let search = UISearchBar() // Create your search bar
controller.navigationController.navigationItem.titleView = search
```