# searchBar not centered in navigationItem

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, navigationitem

**Current status**
[image: Current Status]

I am doing it programmatically. I also tried to set it into TitleView, but it's not working. 
Code below:

```
        //searchBar
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search Players"
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
    definesPresentationContext = true
```

I also have a ScopeBar under the searchBar, when selected.
If I do it like:

```
searchController.titleView = searchController.searchBar
```

It goes in place, but I cannot select/tap the searchBar anymore.

Comment: If you want to achieve search suggestions use `UISearchController` , otherwise use normal `UISearchBar`

Comment: You might wanna look at this question and it's corresponding answers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38589999/center-search-bar-in-navigation-controller-swift

Answer (score 0):

For me, your example works well, but maybe you canuse it.

```
   navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar
```

You can insert search bar into navigation like here.
Can you explain what's wrong with search bar in table view header? What isn't work?

Comment: Thanks. 
.titleView is working but the search bar becomes not selectable. I Will add details on the question.

Comment: It's very strange behavior, maybe something wrong with navigation bar, need to see more details.

Answer (score 0):

if your iOS version greater than ios11 or equal you should add like this

```
navigationItem.searchController = searchController
```

else

```
navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar
```

and also you should give more detail

Comment: thanks. The problem is that when I make it equal to .titleView, the searchBar goes into place, but cannot be selected anymore and it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

One way to go would be using the bounds to set it to center manually. But on the searchbar activation(click) it would be again messed up and needed to be set again.

```
searchController.searchBar.bounds=CGRectInset(searchController.searchBar.frame, 0.0f, -2.5f);
```